# Could someone validate this logic proof for me?

Tags: logic, solution-verification

Prove that if the sentence (∀x P (x)) ∨ (∀x Q(x)) holds, then ∀x (P (x) ∨ Q(x)) holds too

Assume $\forall x$ P(x) = True

$\forall x$ (P(x)$\lor$Q(x)) must be true by assumption.

By symmetry this must be hold if Q(x) is true for all x

Comment: Why "by assumption"?

Comment: Perhaps I did not make this clear enough, I will edit to reflect this is my assumption If ∀ P(x) = True

Comment: Ok, the result is fine, but the argument is quite obscure.. in a nutshell you are saying that the conclusion holds because the premise is true.

Comment: Your argument doesn't look correct.

Comment: Could you explain how I should approach this then @ryang

Comment: @treebluefire The premise is "A or B", so you cannot just assume that $A$ is true.  On the other hand, if the premise is "A and B" instead, then you can assume that $A$ is true.